# Fade in each li one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fade each nav `li` one by one. Here's my current code. It shows the whole div, now I want to fade in each `li` one by one with a slight delay.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#circleMenuBtn").click(function(){
        $("#dropDownMenu").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li> First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <li>Fifth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    color: #fff;
    right: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

I tried for loops trying to fade in each `li` in one iteration but no success. Please share your ideas.

**UPDATE**: Rory McCrossan's code is perfect. Unfortunately, it's not compatible with my code that hides the menu when clicked outside it.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#dropDownMenu");

    if (!container.is(e.target)
       && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
       container.fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

What went wrong? I've just started to learn JS and JQuery so please forgive me if it's a lame question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use an `each()` call to loop through the `li` elements and `delay()` the `fadeIn()` animation by an incremental amount. Try this:

```js
$("#dropDownMenu li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    /* color: #fff;
    right: 5px; */
}

.sub-menu li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li> First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <li>Fifth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to increase/decrease the interval between items fading, change the value provided to the `delay()` method. In this example I used `100ms`.

*Update* - to achieve the same effect in plain JS you can use a timeout and `transition` the opacity in CSS, like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#dropDownMenu li").forEach((li, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    li.classList.add('show');
  }, 100 * i);
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.sub-menu li {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.sub-menu li.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li> First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution, works like a charm! Why is it conflicting with my code to close the menu though?

Comment: this is a really nice solution!

Comment: @Rory McCrossan How can I use this with pure JS?

Comment: @Verminous added a JS only implementation for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rory McCrossan ! Wasn't sure you'd be there after 6 years :)

Answer (score 21):

If you have a limited number of elements you could also consider using css-animations instead of a javascript solution. 
You can address each element using the nth-child selector and delay its animation according to its position. To make the animation stop at the end use the animation-fill-mode property.

```
li {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 0.9s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:nth-child(5n+1) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

/*...*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

See this example and mind the prefixes
https://jsfiddle.net/97bknLdu/

Comment: +1 for a different solution to the accepted answer.  Worth noting that this won't work on older browsers, those below IE10, apparently.

Comment: What will be the case if we render `li` from a loop?

Comment: According to Fireship, there is a new way to stage css animation using css-variables and *gasp* inline styles. -> https://youtu.be/Qhaz36TZG5Y?t=423

Answer (score 11):

Do something like this with [animation success callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/#fadeIn-duration-complete)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fade(ele) {
    ele.fadeIn(500, function() { // set fade animation fothe emlement
      var nxt = ele.next(); // get sibling next to current eleemnt
      if (nxt.length) // if element exist
        fade(nxt); // call the function for the next element
    });
  }
  $("#circleMenuBtn").click(function() {
    fade($('#navbar li').eq(0)); // call the function with first element
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #000;
  right: 5px;
}
ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="circleMenuBtn">click</button>
```