# jQuery Showing List Item One by One Looping Not Working

Tags: jquery, animation, setinterval

Basically, once page load, I want to show the list item one by one, and once all fully showing, I want to hide all back and repeat showing those items one by one again.

Please see my code below and tell what I do wrong.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    setInterval(
      (function x() {
        var delay = 1000;
        $('ul.banner-point > li').each(function() {
          $(this).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn(1850).addClass('text-bigger').delay(100).queue(function(next) {
            $(this).removeClass('text-bigger');
            next();
          });
          delay += 1000;
        });
      })(), 5000);
 
});
```

```css
.text-bigger {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ed3b49;
}

ul.banner-point li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="banner-point">
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 1</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 2</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 3</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 4</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 5</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;" ><span>Point 6</span></li>
</ul>
```

*I know about this question: [Fade in each li one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109870/fade-in-each-li-one-by-one). However, the solution there does not include looping. What I'm trying to do now is to include a loop.*

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem right, try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function x() {
        var delay = 1000;
        var li_count = $('ul.banner-point > li').length -1;
        $('ul.banner-point > li').each(function (i) {
            $(this).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn(1850).addClass('text-bigger').delay(100).queue(function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass('text-bigger');
                if (li_count == i) x();
                next();
            });
            delay += 1000;
        });
    }
    x();
});
```

```css
.text-bigger {
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #ed3b49;
}

ul.banner-point li {
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="banner-point">
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 1</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 2</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 3</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 4</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 5</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><span>Point 6</span></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```